# Mpeg1, vp9, theora and h264 intra lossless encoding strange results

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg, vp9, ogg-theora

I tried lossless intra coding of a few sequences including this one from xiph.org:
https://media.xiph.org/video/derf/y4m/foreman_qcif.y4m
and strangely mpeg1video wins by a great margin sizewise. I used FFmpeg with these settings:

```
ffmpeg -i foreman_qcif.y4m -c:v mpeg1video -qscale:v 0 -intra foreman.mpeg
ffmpeg -i foreman_qcif.y4m -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -intra foreman.mp4
ffmpeg -i foreman_qcif.y4m -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 0 -intra foreman.webm
ffmpeg -i foreman_qcif.y4m -c:v libtheora -qscale:v 10 -intra foreman.ogg
```

And the sizes I've got: mpeg1video - 2643968; theora - 2949677; vp9 - 5636841; h264 - 5743014;
So the question is: does mpeg1video really beats them all by such a margin in this mode ?

Comment: Did you confirm it is actually lossless?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently even on the max quality settings mpeg1video is far from being lossless. From ISO-IEC-11172-2_1991_MPEG1_Video:"algorithm is not lossless" and "The "quantizer size for the DC coefficients of the luminance and chrominance components is fixed at eight"